# IS auto-shutdown causes SLR to stop detecting lens - Canon 70-200 2.8L IS MK I

Tags: lens, canon, repair, image-stabilization

I've tested this on my 6D and my friends' 60D.

Use case:
[Only occurs in Video mode]
1) Activate the IS function during Video mode. Does not have to be recording (but is reproducible in the same manner if recording).
2) Stop triggering the IS by letting go of the shutter button OR just start recording the video.
3) IS auto-shutdown after a few seconds.
4) Mirror snaps down; Camera displays "Ensure a lens is attached" error message immediately after IS stops (you can hear the IS stopping).

Very irritating since I now can't use my 70-200 to record any video unless I turn IS off.

Does not happen when I have the LCD on in shooting mode or any other situation. To have my lens serviced at a Canon repair depot would cost me $280 (default baseline price), which is a bit of a bummer since I don't even know what's wrong.

I bought this lens used from a previous CPS member in San Francisco when I was intern'ing there and the lens truly looks like it's in great shape. It was last serviced in Nov. 2011 and had a back seal replaced. Has anyone attempted a fix or teardown on this lens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lens was broken. I had to send it into Canon and get a repair done. $300 down :(.

Answer (score 0):

While I haven't experienced this directly, I did some digging and came across [this](http://forums.redflagdeals.com/70-200-2-8l-rev-1-6d-ensure-lens-attached-video-mode-1438634/) forum post which, while it didn't find a solution to the problem, seems to indicate that it is the shutdown of the IS motor that is the problem and that the IS shuts down if it hasn't recieved a signal for a half press in a while.

If this is in fact the case, then returning it to Canon for repair may not make any difference as it may not actually be a problem with the lens, but rather a limitation of the lens.

Comment: While this seems correct, this should not be true. I contacted Canon and they said this was unexpected behaviour. Furthermore, if you take my 24-105L and attempt to reproduce the behaviour (the IS on it also performs auto-shutoff), the IS knows not to shut off in video mode and continues to run. // Afterthought - maybe the fact that the lens is 10 years old may mean that this lens was never designed to keep its IS running as opposed to the 24-105L.

Comment: @MarkS - the newer II version of the 70-200 IS also will keep it running in video mode, but who knows if the original one knows how.   If Canon says it should work, then it probably should work though.

Comment: Turns out my lens was broken. :( I had it repaired a few months ago and forgot about this question.